# uploading images using HTML5 and PHP

Tags: php

If i read file upload script I see almost everywhere the following line of code to read the file contents

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

But unfortunately can't really understand it. Can someone please help what does it actually mean?

Comment: But unfortunately can't really understand first line. Can someone please help what does it actually mean?

Comment: Instead of `file_get_contents('php://input')` I generally see usage of  `$_FILES["images"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although your post isn't too detailed in what you have tried to accomplish and most importantly, how, I will attempt to provide some guidelines to solving your problem.

**1. How do uploads work?**

The first thing you must understand, how uploads work with PHP. The file you upload is sent as the body part of the HTTP request.

This body part however may be encoded. Once such encoding may be `multipart/form-data`, where the body is divided into separate parts. PHP however does some special processing to this, see later on in this answer.

An other method is to send the file itself completely unencoded as the body part of a `PUT` request, sent by for example `XMLHttpRequest`. This would enable your code to actually work, but again, let's discuss this later.

**2. How does PHP handle uploads?**

PHP has some special magic if you use `multipart/form-data`. If you use this, the contents of `php://input` will not be available, instead you must use the `$_FILES` array to handle your upload.

If you on the other hand want to process the upload yourself or you used the PUT method and your upload doesn't require special processing, you can just read all contents of `php://input` and use them any way you like.

For more details on uploads please see the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

**3. How to submit files from the client?**

There are several methods. The most basic method is to simply create a form that submits the file as a `HTTP POST` upload and then handle it as described above.

If you want a progress bar, you can use some Flash like the [YUI uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/). This little file will still send a `HTTP POST`, but you will have access to how much was uploaded via JavaScript.

Finally, if your browser supports the HTML5 File API, you can get the contents of a local file and upload it via `HTTP POST` or `HTTP PUT` according to your needs. For more details see [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

**4. Debugging problems**

Stuff tends to break, so you'll need to be able to debug it. Your first weapon of choice would be some sort of network dump from your browser. If you have Chrome, the tools are build in, for other browsers you might have to download some extensions.

You need to look at the request and see if the data is there and it's encoded correctly. As a web developer you should posses a deep understanding of HTTP, so if you don't [read up on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). **There is no excuse for not knowing HTTP.**

If you are sure your data arrives on the server side, you should learn to debug PHP. First of all, take a look at your [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). Is everything there you sent? Or is something missing?

If you don't have the file you sent, you may have hit the configured filesize limits for uploads, either in your webserver or in your PHP. As to which the culprit is, you will have to find out for yourself.

Also, be sure to set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & E_NOTICE` so you don't miss problems with your code.

Finally, if nothing else helps, you will need to learn to debug with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). Again, **there is no excuse whatsoever for a web developer for not being able to debug your own code.** None.

Comment: +1 for a very thoughtful answer

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php.

`php://input` is a "special file" which contains the *input* that was sent to the PHP script. On a web server that means the contents of the HTTP **request body**. `file_get_contents` simply reads the entire contents, like from a regular file.

In short: that line gets the content of the HTTP request body.

However: `php://input` is [not populated](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=23765) when using `multipart/form-data`